# Computationally indistinguishability using DDH assumption

Tags: diffie-hellman

This is part of the explanation of the commitment scheme from DDH in this lecture notes by Vipul Goyal: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~goyal/s18/15503/scribe_notes/lecture22.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Egoyal/s18/15503/scribe_notes/lecture22.pdf)

My question is not directly related to the content of the pdf, but in page 20-4, it says
$\{g, g^a, g^b, m \cdot g^r |(a, b, r) \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_q\}$ is computationally indistinguishable from $\{g, g^a, g^b, g^r |(a, b, r) \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_q\}$. Why is that necessarily true? Can anyone please formally explain why that’s the case? Also, when texts describe distributions in such way, are the two $(a, b, r)$’s in the two distributions equal? Or is it just that the symbols are same, but they are in fact independently selected at random from $\mathbb{Z}_q$?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to crypto.stackexchange. I'm confused because page 20-4 literally has a step-by-step justification for why those two distributions are indistinguishable. Is there a more specific step that doesn't make sense?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the equation that is between 'But' and 'So we have' on page 20-4, but I think yacovm's answer helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this $m$ is some element in the group $\mathbb{G}$ so there exists some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ such that $m=g^{\alpha}$, hence $m \cdot g^r = g^{\alpha+r}$ and notice that since $r$ is selected uniformly at random from $\mathbb{Z}_q$, then the distribution of $\alpha + r$ is exactly (not just computationally but exactly) uniform in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ as well.

Intuitively you can think of $r+\alpha$ as taking $\alpha$ which someone selected for you, and then adding to it a random number modulo $q$, and it is exactly uniform because for every possible result of $r+\alpha$ there is exactly a single $r$ that makes it that result, hence it is uniform.

As for the (a,b,r) - keep in mind, that the DDH assumption is trying to say something like: If you look at two random group elements $g^a, g^b$ and you have a third group element $h\in\mathbb{G}$, then you don't know if $h=g^{a\cdot b}$ or that $h$ is some completely random, unrelated group element $g^r$ for some random $r$.
The way you write this, is you look at two distributions where the $g^a, g^b$ are the same in both sides of the equality, but the third element is different (it is either $g^{a \cdot b}$ or $g^r$ and you say that under the DDH assumption, there doesn't exist an efficient probabilistic polynomial time turing machine that can distinguish  between $g^{a \cdot b}$ and a random group element.

Comment: Thanks! How about the second question? In such notations, are the $a, b, r$ equal values for the two distributions, or are they randomly picked separately?

Comment: I updated the answer, tell me if it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, I understood your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, happy to help